# LWC: Select/Deselect all Checkboxes with a Single Checkbox

Tags: lightning-web-components

How to select and deselect all using lwc and I have multiple checkboxes on the page

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle"
                onchange={changeToggle}></lightning-input>
....
....
<lightning-input data-id="toggle10" type="toggle"
                onchange={selectall}></lightning-input>
```

JS

```
selectall(event) {
        let i; 
        let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id="toggle"]')
        for(i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = event.target.checked;
        }
    }
```

the above code works if all my checkboxes `data-id="toggle"` but I just want to keep the data-id unique is there a way I can say starting with `toggle` and ignore the numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want to get every lightning input which data-id starts with "toggle" your selector should be: `[data-id^="toggle"]`
You can find the whole list of CSS attribute selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Then if you want to check/uncheck them all via a single input your `selectall` method needs only a slightly change

```
selectall(event) {
    const toggleList = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-id^="toggle"]');
    for (const toggleElement of toggleList) {
        toggleElement.checked = event.target.checked;
    }
}
```